# If and else statements in Python 3

Tags: windows, python-3.x, if-statement

I am learning python and would like to create a text based windows 7 app launcher. I hope to have this running in a command-prompt soon. My code worked until I added the else statement. Now everything resolves to the last line of 'that is not an option' 
without the else statement I could type google and launch google.exe no problem. I am going to continue to search on the interwebs for an answer but also thought this might be a good way to see how this can be done in other ways. I plan to use elif statement and launch more than one application.
Here is my code so far.

```
import os
print("***********")
print("Choices")
print("************")
print("google")
choice1 = "google"
input("choose your Task... ")
if input == choice1:
    os.chdir(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application')
    os.startfile('chrome.exe')
else:
    print("That is not an option")
```

It's pretty basic but it is a starting point.

Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The else is actually working as intended there. The problem lies in your usage of [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

The [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function returns the answer the user gives as a string. So if you change your code to instead say:

`input = input("choose your Task... ")`

Then now your check for `if input == choice1:` will work as intended.

Comment: To expand a little here in case it's helpful, your line where you say `if input == choice1:` is checking if the value of the variable **input** is equal to the value of the variable **choice1**.

Since you never set the variable **input** to anything, then your check of `if input == choice1:` is _always_ failing, causing the `else` portion of your code to always run.

Comment: thanks Austin, I think I understand. I made the changes you suggested however still the else statement prints and chrome dose not launch.

Comment: Could you reply with the code as it is now? I may be able to still help.

Comment: never mind I had a duh moment. there was 2 == in my input = input line. Now everything is working great!

Thanks again.